# Google Maps API Javascript: Activating infowindows on markers from Places search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a Places search box by strictly following Google developer [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). Markers will be displayed on the Map, based on the specific search term (e.g. "restaurants"). Of course I want to show an infowindow when a user clicks on a marker, to actually give the user some information about the Place. I have followed Google developers [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?csw=1#placeid) in order to activate the infowindows, withouth any success (the changes I have made in the code are illustrated by comments 1, 2 and 3).

Earlier posts here didn't help me out either. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});


// 1: Variables infowindow and service:

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

var markers = [];

searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
   var places = searchBox.getPlaces(); 

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {

        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
  });

// 2: getDetails, referring to the "places" (var places = searchBox.getPlaces();) already on the map
// 3: addlistener on the markers, to show an infowindow upon a clickevent   

  service.getDetails(places, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
          'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
          place.formatted_address + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
  });



  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});


}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the details request when the marker is clicked (if you run all the details requests when you create the markers you will run into the query limit).

Then open the infowindow on the marker when the response comes back.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  // 1: Variables infowindow and service:
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var markers = [];
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location,
          placeId: place.place_id
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
          // 2: getDetails, referring to the "places" (var places = searchBox.getPlaces();) already on the map
          // 3: addlistener on the markers, to show an infowindow upon a clickevent   

          service.getDetails({
            placeId: this.placeId
          }, (function(marker) {
            return function(place, status) {
              if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                  'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                  place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
            }
          }(marker)));
        });
        if (place.geometry.location) {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      })
      // map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" type="text" />
<div id="map"></div>
```